# Early abandon discord searching in Time-Series using saxpy

Tags: deep-learning, time-series, sax

I am trying to look for discords (the most unusual, least similar shape) in a data-set using time-series. I came across [this](https://www.pydoc.io/pypi/saxpy-1.0.1.dev167/autoapi/discord/index.html) function in the saxpy package that outputs the discord shape. However, the link above is the only documentation that I could find and the input parameters to the function haven't been explained very well there.

More specifically,

```
find_best_discord_brute_force(series, win_size, global_registry, z_threshold=0.01)
```

What do the parameters `win_size, global_registry` stand for?
Also, does the `series` parameter require me to input SAX words?

It would be great if someone could clear this up.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Matrix Profile instead. Is it faster and simpler, and there is free code, see this presentation

http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Matrix_Profile_Tutorial_Part1.pdf

Comment: I was actually studying the paper about using PAA-SAX for finding discords by Keogh and the other authors. I wanted to use these codes to cross-verify the results produced by the algorithms proposed in the paper to what the code in that link gives.

Answer (score -2):

series is a numpy array of the data whose discords you are looking for.
win_size is the size of the sliding window used by sax_via_window for calculating the words representing your array.

Sorry, not sure what global_registry refers to.

For further information and documentation, there's documentation on github: https://github.com/seninp/saxpy

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)